# How to use read() to get input of unknown length from stdin

Tags: c, input, scanf

Until now, whenever I wanted to get user input from *stdin* I used `scanf()` but this time I can't and **have** to use `read()`.

Usually, to get input from *stdin* using `read` I use:

```
char buf[128];
read(0, buf, sizeof(buf));
```

But this time I don't have any length limit to the input and I want to allow input with arbitrary size. In the past I used `scanf` for this, like so:

```
char *user_input;   
scanf("%ms", &user_input);
```

How can I do this with `read()`?
*Note: safety isn't important here*

Comment: Basically to read one line you read character by character until you encounter a `\n`. But _why_  do you need to use `read` ?

Comment: `read(0, buf, sizeof(buf));` I hope you're not expecting `buf` to contain a string after that.

Comment: Don't use `recv` as a variable name, it confused me because [recv()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) is a POSIX function.

Comment: The `m` prefix in the `"%ms"` format is an *extension*, it's not part of the [standard `scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). As such you should really try to avoid it.

Comment: I use `read` because of implementations limits. And yes, the input is only one line and `read` would automatically stop when it reaches `\n` - this is by design. But how should `read()` gets its parameters in case I defined `recv` as: `char *recv; `, because `reads` gets length which is unknown for me.

Comment: Did you conisder reading a fragment of size 128 into a 128 buffer, then find out whether there is more and read more in the next buffer?

Comment: If you don't know the length you might be reading, then there are two options: Either you read and allocate dynamically one character at a time, reallocating as needed; Or you have an array long enough to hold the maximum length of a line, and still read one character at a time.

Comment: BTW: `read()` returns a value. Use it!

Comment: By the way, [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) with the `"%s"` format stops at *any* whitespace, not just newlines. If you want to read a line and automatically allocate memory, then I suggest [`getline`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) instead.

Comment: Use a buffer. Read into the buffer. If you haven't read to the end of the line, realloc the buffer to be larger, keep reading until you get a short read, or you've read past the newline. Future reads need to remember that you could have still things to read in the buffer. This is what `scanf` and family do internally.

Comment: Lastly a little bit of a nitpicking... While `0` is known to be standard input, using [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) is considered bad. On a POSIX system use `STDIN_FILENO` instead.

Comment: Is "arbitrary size" means the line could be any length like 100, 1 million, or 1 trillion?  To prevent hacker abuse, setting a sane upper limit is wise.

Answer (score 1):

The function `read` returns the number of read bytes. You can take advantage of this information and loop until you read 0 bytes, that is, `read` returns 0.

```
char buf[BUF_SIZE]; // Set BUF_SIZE to the maximum number of character you expect to read (e.g. 1000 or 10000 or more).
int bytes_to_read, total_read_bytes, read_bytes;

// Number of bytes to read at each iteration of the loop.
bytes_to_read = 128;

// The following variable counts the number of total read bytes. 
total_read_bytes = 0;

while ((read_bytes = read(0, buf + total_read_bytes, bytes_to_read) != 0) {

    if (read_bytes < 0) {
        // read() may return -1. You can look at the variable errno to
        // have more details about the cause of the error.
        return -1;
    }

    total_read_bytes += read_bytes;
}
```

Notice that `read` does **not** automatically append the null terminator `\0` to `buf`, that is, `buf` is not a string until you explicitly add `\0` at the end of it.

```
...
// Making buf a string.
buf[total_read_bytes] = '\0';
...
```

Comment: @wildplasser thank you. Trying to improve myself here on stack overflow. Is it better now?

Answer (score -3):

one way is run a loop with getchar() function and keep rading the characters into an array. check the array size with each iteration ,Once the array is full, reallocate it to a larger size. OR use the The getline() function.
link for [getline()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html)

Check the below programme .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    char *lines = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    ssize_t res = getline(&line, &n, stdin);
    free(line);
}
```

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer. And he states he wants to use `read`.